# .NET Web Forms - missing "run at server" right click on HTML from toolbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I'm following a tutorial to set up a web form, as I have to be able to modify existing ones at work and thought I'd get to grips with how they work. In the tutorial it says using the `Toolbox` I should be able to add the standard `HTML` elements and then right click on them and select `Run at Server` to convert them to Web Form elements.

Only problem is that I can't see this? I was wondering whether the tutorial I was using is using an older version of Visual Studio and these features have now been retired in 2015, or whether I have additional settings that I need to set up?

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't seem to support conversion of HTML controls to Web Form controls anymore (verified on my computer running VS2015), while it was possible in Visual Studio 2005. I'm afraid you'll have to convert them manually by adding the *runat="server"* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Go to source and convert it.
For example

```
<input type="text" name="name" runat="server" >
```